# Are nested synchronized blocks allowed in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, multithreading, recursion

I read in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883742/nested-synchronized-keyword) that in Java, nested synchronised blocks are allowed. I know that Objective-C's synchronised blocks look a lot like Java's. So I wonder: Are nested blocks allowed in Objective-C?

I also have a side question: Is there a practical limit on recursive blocks?

Thank you for your speedy answer!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, they are. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocThreading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH19-SW1) (now retired):

> The Objective-C synchronization feature supports recursive and reentrant code. A thread can use a single semaphore several times in a recursive manner; other threads are blocked from using it until the thread releases all the locks obtained with it; that is, every @synchronized() block is exited normally or through an exception.

For a discussion of performance with this and other methods of synchronization/locking, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100107134201/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLockVsSynchronized).

Comment: Thanks @bkbeachlabs. I've updated my links to point to old/archived versions of what they used to be. I'm not sure where you can find this "`@synchronized` is reentrant" guarantee in the current docs.

Comment: It can now be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocThreading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH19-SW1

"The Objective-C synchronization feature supports recursive and reentrant code. A thread can use a single semaphore several times in a recursive manner; other threads are blocked from using it until the thread releases all the locks obtained with it; that is, every @synchronized() block is exited normally or through an exception."